# How to make Mutual Fund - SIP Calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, sip

I am making a SIP Calculator for website/blog. But don't know how should I start. I have created a basic html CSS version but don't know how to calculate the numbers.

Comment: Can you please give me the formula for calculating sip?

Comment: Hey Keshav please check out this website and its backend.- http://sipcalculator.in/

Comment: That page doesn't provides the formula as it uses php.

Comment: please refer this articles : 1. https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/invest/heres-how-you-can-calculate-returns-on-mutual-fund-sip/articleshow/53841350.cms           2.http://www.onemint.com/2011/05/15/how-to-calculate-returns-from-a-sip-systematic-investment-plan/

Comment: You can check this site https://www.mutualfunds-calculator.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var investment = 800; //principal amount
  var annualRate = 2; 
  var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;  //Rate of interest
  var years = 30; 
  var months = years * 12;  //Time period 
  var futureValue = 0; //Final Value

  futureValue = investment * (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months) - 1) / 
monthlyRate;
```

SIP is nothing but just Compound interest amount on Principal amount.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#btn-sip').click(function(event) {

    var investment = $('#inv-amount').val(); // Total investment
    var years = $('#inv-period').val(); // No of years
    var annualRate = $('#inv-exreturn').val(); // annual Rate

        if (investment == '' || years == '' || annualRate == '') {
            alert('please enter all values');
        } else {
            var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;
            var months = years * 12;
            var futureValue = 0;

        var total = ((investment*years*annualRate));

        futureValue=(investment * (1+monthlyRate) * ((Math.pow((1+monthlyRate),months)) - 1)/monthlyRate);

        $('#total-investment').val(Math.round(total));
        $('#end-value').val(Math.round(futureValue));

        $('#sip-cal-result').css('display', 'block');
        }
});
```